# How to start Azure emulator at custom domain?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, azure, localhost, azure-emulator

Every time I launch the Azure emulator, it points to `http://127.0.0.1`. This doesn't work for me because I use Facebook log in, which doesn't support numbers. So what I've done is this:

- I set `'mydomain.com'` as my domain for my Facebook app. I set `dev.mydomain.com` as the return URL for the app.
- I created a record in my HOST file, pointing `127.0.0.1` to `dev.mydomain.com` (according to [Azure emulator web site is not visible by Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169641/azure-emulator-web-site-is-not-visible-by-facebook)).
- I updated my Web role project to use `http://localhost` with a application root URL override to `http://dev.mydomain.com`, and I created a virtual directory for that. I also set the start URL for the project to `http://dev.mydomain.com`.
- I edited `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` to use `*:80:dev.mydomain.com` (according to [Using Custom Domains With IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express)).

So I'd say I have everything in place to make this work. But every time I start the Azure emulator, it launches `http://127.0.0.1`. How do I make it launch `http://dev.mydomain.com` instead?

Anyone?

Comment: Are you just asking how to get the browser to open with a different URL? Why don't you just type in `dev.mydomain.com` after the browser opens?

Comment: That's a possibility, but it's highly annoying, I just want it to start at dev.mydomain.com.

Comment: You might want to edit your question, then... there are a lot of irrelevant details, like how you configured Facebook and your hosts file. I'd suggest simply "Is it possible to have the Windows Azure emulator open the browser to a URL other than 127.0.0.1?" I believe the answer is "no," but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it has any other implications than just the URL it is launched at. It seems to be working if I manually enter another URL, but I'm haven't tested it thoroughly.